# What is the correct method to calculate ELF?

Tags: density-functional-theory, quantum-espresso

I am trying to calculate the electron localization function (ELF) using Quantum ESPRESSO.
However, I realize that it is not possible to correctly calculate it with either the Ultrasoft or the PAW pseudopotentials.

With ultrasoft pseudos, the method is *not implemented fully*, while with the PAW pseudopotentials, as per an old answer [here](https://narkive.com/10wFnvfE:2.689.38), seems to indicate that ELF with PAW is also not implemented.

As detailed in the answer [here](https://narkive.com/F2GAQGzz:2.375.462): "The correct calculation of the ELF with ultrasoft pseudopotentials or with PAW requires to compute the contribution from augmentation charges."

Can someone guide that how this contribution maybe computed? Alternatively, is there an other software that can the ELF correctly for a periodic system?

Any insights provided would be much helpful.

Comment: I gave my +1 long ago, but since it has been more than 6 months, is there any update you can provide us? Are you still urgently or actively in need of an answer to this question? Please let us know!

Comment: @NikeDattani No, I don't have an update in this regard. This question could be closed since its been open for so long without any response

Comment: Thanks, if anyone wants to write an answer, we can easily re-open the question if they leave a comment here. You can also ask to have it reopened if you become increased need for an answer in the future.